# java - recursion code explanation (check if ascending)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am recently finished creating a program that checks if a user-inputted int array is arranged in ascending order. I have my function isAsc here:

```
public static boolean isAsc(int[] arr, int index){
    if (index==1 || arr.length==1){
        return true; //Base case
    }
    else if (arr[index-2] >= arr[index-1]){
        return false; 
    }
    else
        return isAsc(arr, index-1); //recursive step
}
```

And the logic seems to be correct. However, what I don't get is when I call the function: `System.out.print(isAsc(arr, arrayLength-1));`

the output is wrong. This  `System.out.print(isAsc(arr, arrayLength));`
yields the correct answer. Why? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output you see?  What is the array you used?

Comment: Your logic returns false when there are duplicate numbers, even though they are sorted correctly (adjacent). Change `>=` to `>`.

Comment: @Malvolio 1 2 4 3 and it returns true. anyways, i got it figured out now thanks

Comment: @Bohemian, yes I made it like that.

Comment: @PaulStevenFantonalgoNadera -- your error is so common, it has [its own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling the method with

```
isAsc(arr, arr.length-1)
```

your method never checks the last element of the array in the `if (arr[index-2] >= arr[index-1])` check, so the output may be incorrect.

On the other hand, when you call it with

```
isAsc(arr, arr.length)
```

the first execution of your method checks `if (arr[index-2] >= arr[index-1])`, or in other words `if (arr[arr.length-2] >= arr[arr.length-1])` (assuming your array has multiple elements), so `arr[arr.length-1]` is not skipped.

Comment: Ohhhh, I got it now. I had to write everything with pen and paper to understand, lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: I should've used index-1 >= index instead lol I'm used to declaring arr.length-1. thanks again